# Ruby on Rails : how to test a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning Ruby.
I'm now trying to test one of my controller.

My test file is **myapp/test/testing.rb** while my controller is located at **myapp/app/controllers/test_controller.rb**.

The content of **testing.rb** is

```
data = testController.mymethod()
puts(data)
```

But when doing

```
ruby myapp/test/testing.rb
```

in the terminal, I get a warning :

> Traceback (most recent call last):myapp/test/testing.rb:6:in `':
>   uninitialized constant testController (NameError)

Could someone explain me what i'm doing is wrong and how I should do this ?

Thanks !

Comment: why downvoted ?

Comment: Did you have a look at the official [Rails Guides about Testing](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers)?

Comment: "Could someone explain me how what i'm doing wrong" - pretty much everything. `testController` is most likely mispelt. `mymethod` is an instance method and not a class method. And finally this is not how you test controllers at all.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Well, I've got to learn somehow.  Sorry to ask...

Answer (score 7):

The currently accepted way to [test rails controllers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#implementing-an-integration-test) is by sending http requests to your application and writing assertions about the response.

Rails has `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` which provides integration tests for Minitest which is the Ruby standard library testing framework. Using the older approach of mocking out the whole framework with `ActionDispatch::ControllerTest` is no longer recommended for new applications.

This is your basic "Hello World" example of controller testing:

```
require 'test_helper'

class BlogFlowTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "can see the welcome page" do
    get "/"
    assert_select "h1", "Welcome#index"
  end
end
```

You can also use RSpec which is different test framework with a large following. In RSpec you write [request specs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec) which are just a thin wrapper on top of ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest.

Answer (score 1):

RSpec is DSL written on Ruby special for this purpose. You have to be familiar with it to write tests of your code. As for RSpec team note: 
`

> The official recommendation of the Rails team and the RSpec core team is to write request specs instead. Request specs allow you to focus on a single controller action, but unlike controller tests involve the router, the middleware stack, and both rack requests and responses. This adds realism to the test that you are writing, and helps avoid many of the issues that are common in controller specs. In Rails 5, request specs are significantly faster than either request or controller specs were in rails 4.

So you have to write `request`specs for your controller. Something like this: 
`spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb`

```rb
RSpec.describe "Test", type: :request do
  describe "request list of all tests" do
    user = User.create(email: 'test@user.com', name: 'Test User')
    get users_path
    expect(response).to be_successful
    expect(response.body).to include("Test User")
  end
end
```

Something like this. Hope it will help

Comment: There is a lot thats just wrong about this answer. Rails has always officially endorsed first test unit and then minitest. RSpec is generic BDD framework and is not "written on Ruby special for this purpose" unless you just mean testing in general. rspec-rails has always also just been a bunch of wrappers around the test case classes that rails had for minitest/testunit. Don't get me wrong - I love RSpec. But in 2020 its not really that correct to point to RSpec as "the way to write RoR tests".

Comment: I think it's still the best intro to rails testing - rspec. We've been doing it this way ^ for a decade, things are fine. The question is by a newcomer, so he probably wants something simple before getting into the depth of (non-rails) ruby.

Comment: please link the source of the quote :)